# How to solve CSC = sin-1?

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to get some help on this. I'm trying to help my friend solve this but it had been over 14 years since I did this type. All I have to work with is this.

Sorry if it is vague. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cosecant = cscx=1/sinx.

[image]

Comment: Does $\sin^{-1}$ return values in radians or degrees?

Comment: Should return degrees....

Comment: I have added a picture for reference.

Comment: What's more to prove? You have shown $cosecx=\frac {1}{sinx} $

Comment: The picture has $$\frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{\text{hyp}}{\text{opp}}$$ immediately (and incorrectly) followed by $$\sin x=\frac{\text{hyp}}{\text{opp}}$$

Comment: @r.e.s. Correct, sorry about that even still with (opp/hyp) it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: CSC still equals sin-1 , and it shouldn't

Comment: I think you are confusing the **reciprocal** and the **inverse** function. The (corrected) picture shows $\csc x = \frac{1}{\sin x}$. It does *not* show $\csc x= \sin^{-1}x$.

Comment: i know they are tow different functions but the work i did shows that they are equal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37995/discussion-between-r-e-s-and-justin).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are confusing the inverse sine $\sin^{-1}$ with the reciprocal.  $\sin^{-1}$ does NOT mean sin raised to the negative one power it means the inverse function also called the arcsin